# If I want to prove that a problem is in NP, can the vertifier use exponential space?

Tags: np, decision-problem

I want to prove that a problem is in NP. I have a witness (of polynomial size), and a verifier that runs in polynomial time. However, this verifier uses exponential space, becuase it has to generate strings of exponential size. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your verifier (a Turing machine) runs in polynomial time then it must also use polynomial space since you can write at most one tape cell (or a constant number of tape-cell in case of multi-tape machines) per time-step.

In other words $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{PSPACE}$.